# Rust termion crate: how to clear a single character?

Tags: rust, tui

I'm trying to implement a simple text editor using the [termion](https://crates.io/crates/termion) crate. When the user presses Backspace, I'd like to erase a single character - but I can't figure out how to achieve that.

The crate seems to only offer [these options](https://docs.rs/termion/1.5.6/termion/clear/index.html):

```
AfterCursor     Clear everything after the cursor.
All             Clear the entire screen.
BeforeCursor    Clear everything before the cursor.
CurrentLine     Clear the current line.
UntilNewline    Clear from cursor to newline.
```

None of which sound fitting. `UntilNewLine` sort of works, unless you let the user move the cursor to the left, in which case it deletes more than 1 character (basically the remainder of the line).

My current code:

```
fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();

    write!(stdout, "{}{}", termion::clear::All, termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1));
    stdout.flush().unwrap();

    for c in stdin.keys() {
        match c.unwrap() {
            Key::Esc => break,
            Key::Left => {
                let (x, y) = stdout.cursor_pos().unwrap();
                write!(stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Goto(x-1, y));
            },
            Key::Right => {
                let (x, y) = stdout.cursor_pos().unwrap();
                write!(stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Goto(x+1, y));
            },
            Key::Up => {
                let (x, y) = stdout.cursor_pos().unwrap();
                write!(stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Goto(x, y-1));
            },
            Key::Down => {
                let (x, y) = stdout.cursor_pos().unwrap();
                write!(stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Goto(x, y+1));
            },
            Key::Backspace => {
                let (x, y) = stdout.cursor_pos().unwrap();
                write!(stdout, "{}{}", termion::cursor::Goto(x-1, y), termion::clear::UntilNewline );
            },
            Key::Char('\n') => { write!(stdout, "\r\n"); },
            Key::Char(x) => { write!(stdout, "{}", x); },
            _ => ()
        }
        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
}
```

I guess I have a two-part question:

1. How do I solve this particular problem (clear a single char)?
2. If the solution is somewhere in the docs, how would I go about finding it? I tried searching for delete / backspace / clear - but that didn't work. Is there something I could have done here, or am I running into the limitation of the library?

Comment: In the past  I've done it like this: https://github.com/peterjoel/inspector/blob/9d924e52862476b80fb143e6ef415e1f7878d7af/cli/src/console.rs#L299. That is, define a more abstract model which can be updated however you please and rendered in a separate step.

Comment: If you want to implement more complicated features., like multi-line selection or different editing modes, you'll find this approach much easier to work with.

Comment: I haven't tried [tui](https://docs.rs/tui/0.15.0/tui/), but it offers more abstraction and features on top of termion. I would _guess_ it will do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To erase a single character, position the cursor before it, and then **print a space** to overwrite the character.

Comment: Smart! for Anyone looking in the future this code worked: `let (x, y) = stdout.cursor_pos().unwrap(); write!(stdout, "{}{}", " ", termion::cursor::Goto(x-1, y));` Thanks for the help.